# Building llvm 6 under Linux Alpine

Tags: build, clang, llvm, alpine-linux, libc++

I am trying to build `llvm 6` on a `Linux Alpine` Docker container.

Here is what I have done, following [these instructions](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html):

- `apk add build-base`
- `apk add python`
- `apk add zlib`
- `svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/RELEASE_600/final/ llvm`
- `svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/tags/RELEASE_600/final/ clang`
- `svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/tags/RELEASE_600/final/ libcxx`

(all `svn` calls in the appropriate folders, obviously)

- Then I make my `build` folder and do `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm`

However, when I get to `make`, after a bit it dies with the following:

```
    [ 11%] Building CXX object projects/libcxx/lib/CMakeFiles/cxx_objects.dir/__/src/algorithm.cpp.o
In file included from /root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/ostream:140:0,
                 from /root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/istream:163,
                 from /root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/random:1646,
                 from /root/llvm/projects/libcxx/src/algorithm.cpp:11:
/root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/locale: In function '_Tp std::__1::__num_get_signed_integral(const char*, const char*, std::__1::ios_base::iostate&, int)':
/root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/locale:739:76: error: there are no arguments to 'strtoll_l' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'strtoll_l' must be available [-fpermissive]
         long long __ll = strtoll_l(__a, &__p2, __base, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);
                                                                            ^
/root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/locale:739:76: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
/root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/locale: In function '_Tp std::__1::__num_get_unsigned_integral(const char*, const char*, std::__1::ios_base::iostate&, int)':
/root/llvm/projects/libcxx/include/locale:779:86: error: there are no arguments to 'strtoull_l' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'strtoull_l' must be available [-fpermissive]
         unsigned long long __ll = strtoull_l(__a, &__p2, __base, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);
                                                                                      ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-noexcept-type'
make[2]: *** [projects/libcxx/lib/CMakeFiles/cxx_objects.dir/build.make:63: projects/libcxx/lib/CMakeFiles/cxx_objects.dir/__/src/algorithm.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Am I missing something, like a dependency? Or is this a known bug that needs fixing? What am I supposed to do to get a working, recent `llvm` + `clang` + `libc++` on Linux Alpine?

Comment: Judging by the look of it I guess it's something with your host compiler and/or stdlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At time of writing, there is [an open pull request](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/3583) to add llvm6 to aports. Because it [involves](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/3583/files) a lot of patches and tweaks, it seems building from source on alpine is not easy to figure out.

So, we have every reason to believe that there will soon be an [official llvm6 package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=llvm6&branch=edge), but until one appears, you can use the APKBUILD from that PR to build llvm from source yourself.

**Install Dependencies**

[*abuild*](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Abuild_and_Helpers) is the utility Alpine uses to compile its packages.

```
apk add alpine-sdk
```

*abuild* will install most of the dependencies you need automatically, but it `diffutils` is missing from the dependency list in the PR.

```
apk add diffutils
```

**Stop being *root***

*abuild* refuses to run as *root*, so if you haven't already, create a user account. I'm using the username *apk*:

```
adduser apk
adduser apk abuild
su - apk
abuild-keygen -a
```

**Clone the PR and compile**

```
git clone --depth=1 -b pr-llvm-6 https://github.com/xentec/aports
cd aports/main/llvm6
abuild -r
```

The `abuild -r` will take a very long time indeed, so if you're following along, now might be a good time to take your lunch break.

**Install the resulting package**

If everything succeeded, *abuild* will have placed a bunch of .apk files in $HOME/packages/main. Assuming again that the user account is named *apk* and its home folder is */home/apk*, then, as root

```
cp /home/apk/.abuild/*.rsa.pub /etc/apk/keys
apk add /home/apk/packages/main/$(uname -m)/*.apk
```

With thanks and credit to the author of the PR: https://github.com/xentec

---

**EDIT: Dockerfile Snippet**

Since your question mentions Docker, here's a `RUN` command you can insert:

```
# Temporary workaround for there not being an llvm6 apk yet
# Open PR for llvm6 package: https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/3583
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258121/building-llvm-6-under-linux-alpine
RUN export BUILD_DEPS='alpine-sdk git diffutils' \
 && apk update \
 && apk add $BUILD_DEPS \
 && adduser -D apk \
 && adduser apk abuild \
 && sudo -iu apk abuild-keygen -a \
 && sudo -iu apk git clone --depth=1 -b pr-llvm-6 https://github.com/xentec/aports \
 && sudo -iu apk sh -xec 'cd aports/main/llvm6; abuild -r' \
 && cp /home/apk/.abuild/*.rsa.pub /etc/apk/keys \
 && apk add /home/apk/packages/main/$(uname -m)/*.apk \
 && deluser --remove-home apk \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/APKINDEX* \
 && apk del --no-cache $BUILD_DEPS
```

Comment: Ok, wait a second. I tried to run your dockerfile and it worked spotlessly. But, is clang installed along with the rest? I’d also need clang and libc++, are they included in the apk? If so, where?

Comment: Not in the APK my instructions generated, but `clang` and `lld` APKBUILDs exist on the PR. You can add more abuild lines to the dockerfile to get these packages as well. (IOW, duplicate the `&& sudo -iu apk sh -xec 'cd aports/main/llvm6; abuild -r' \` line and change the `cd` path

Comment: Sorry, I think I am still missing something. I tried to cd, for example, in `aports/main/clang` and run `abuild -r`, but I get the following error message: `>>> clang: Analyzing dependencies...
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  .makedepends-clang-0:
    masked in: cache
    satisfies: world[.makedepends-clang]
>>> ERROR: clang: all failed`. What kind of dependencies is it missing? How can I get them installed? Sorry...!!

Comment: I'd be happy to add a bounty to the question if I could just get this to work!

Comment: The makedepends line for clang is defined [here](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/3583/files#diff-f61243a2fe263d137644eaeacd2fc75bL12); it looks like what you'll need to do to get clang is first use this trick to install version 6 of `llvm-dev`, `llvm-static`, and `llvm-test-utils`, _then_ do the abuild for clang.

Comment: Worth noting, though, above is a guess -- my original answer is just transcribed notes of me trying to solve the same problem you stated in your question (how get llvm6 in an alpine docker). Since I didn't need clang for what I was doing, I stopped investigating after that.

Answer (score 0):

I used Dan's code and pushed it to DockerHub.
Since it takes a while to build locally, a pre-built image might be useful for some :)
[py36-alpine-llvm6(DockerHub)](https://hub.docker.com/r/danigoland/py36-alpine-llvm6/)